# Python Scrapy Response replace unicodes

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I have a Scrapy request with the following response returned:

```
   {"td_data":"\n\n\t
<div class=\"td-block-span12\">\n\r\n
    <div class="td_module_11 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack" >\r\n
    <div class=\"td-module-thumb\">
        <a href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/sometitle\/\" rel=\"bookmark\" title=\"&#8222;sometitle?\">
        <\/a><\/div>\r\n
            <div class=\"item-details\">\r\n
                <h3 class=\"entry-title td-module-title\">
                <\/h3>\r\n
                <div class=\"td-module-meta-info\">\r\n
                    <span class=\"td-post-date\"><time class=\"entry-date updated td-module-date\" datetime=\"2022-02-11T07:08:32+00:00\" >11. Februar 2022<\/time><\/span>
                        <div
            class=\"td-module-comments\"><a
            href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/sometitle\/#comments\">31<\/a><\/div>                <\/div>\r\n\r\n                <div
            class=\"td-excerpt\">\r\n                    \u201eSome excerpt text\u201c\u00a0\u2013                <\/div>\r\n\r\n                <div
            class=\"td-read-more\">\r\n                    <a
            href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/sometitle\/\">Continue<\/a>\r\n                <\/div>\r\n            <\/div>\r\n\r\n        <\/div>\r\n\r\n        \n\t<\/div>
        <!-- .\/td-block-span12 -->\n\n\t
                            <div class=\"td-block-span12\">\n\r\n
                                <div class=\"td_module_11
                                                                                           td_module_wrap
                                                                                           td-animation-stack\">\r\n            <div
                class=\"td-module-thumb\"><a
                href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/othertitle\/\"
                rel=\"bookmark\" title=\"Some other title\"><\/div>\r\n            <div
                class=\"item-details\">\r\n                <h3 class=\"entry-title td-module-title\"><\/h3>\r\n                <div
                class=\"td-module-meta-info\">\r\n                                                            <span
                class=\"td-post-date\"><time class=\"entry-date updated td-module-date\" datetime=\"2022-02-10T20:12:20+00:00\" >10. Februar 2022<\/time><\/span>                    <div
                class=\"td-module-comments\"><a
                href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/othertitle\/#comments\">58<\/a><\/div>                <\/div>\r\n\r\n                <div
                class=\"td-excerpt\">\r\n  Other excerpt                <\/div>\r\n\r\n                <div
                class=\"td-read-more\">\r\n                    <a
                href=\"http:\/\/www.somesite.net\/2022\/02\/othertitle\/\">continue<\/a>\r\n                <\/div>\r\n            <\/div>\r\n\r\n        <\/div>\r\n\r\n        \n\t<\/div>
            <!-- .\/td-block-span12 -->","td_block_id":"td_uid_47_620641c2d6ce0","td_hide_prev":false,"td_hide_next":false}
```

I don't know why but for some reason everything is marked with newline codings, unicodes etc. I tried to transform everything properly afterwards but I cannot replace the unicodes like \u201e and so one. I mean I could parse the string for every single of those (like looking specifically for \u201e and then the next one and so on), but this would be quite ugly and not robust compared to new codes. What I want to achieve is that the codes will be represented by their equivalent, so for example \u00f6 converts to ö.
I also tried several encoding/decoding steps, but they didn't work. Here is my current scrapy callback method:

```
def pg_parse(self,response):
    print(response.text)
    response_formatted = (u'%s' % response.text)
    #response_formatted = response_formatted.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
    response_formatted = response_formatted.encode("utf-8").decode()
    print(response_formatted)
    response_formatted = response_formatted.replace("\\r","").replace("\\n","").replace("\\t","").replace("                    ","")
    #print(response_formatted)
    for sel in scrapy.Selector(text=response_formatted).xpath('//div[contains(@class, "td_module_11")]'):
        title = sel.xpath('div[contains(@class,"td-module-thumb")]/a/@title').extract()
        link = sel.xpath('div[contains(@class,"td-module-thumb")]/a/@href').extract()
        time = sel.xpath('div[contains(@class,"item-details")]/div[contains(@class,"td-module-meta-info")]/span/time/@datetime').extract()
        comments = sel.xpath('div[contains(@class,"item-details")]/div[contains(@class,"td-module-meta-info")]/div/a/text()').extract()
        desc = [""]# sel.extract()
        excerpt = sel.xpath('div[contains(@class,"item-details")]/div[contains(@class,"td-excerpt")]/text()').extract()
        print(title,link,time,comments,desc,excerpt)
        print("----------------")
```

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7?

Comment: Where are you seeing this output? On the terminal / stdout?

Comment: @Corralien: No I'm on Python 3.10

Comment: @Mortz: On the terminal (cmd where I execute the crawl command)

Comment: The problem is to reproduce your data. Can you update your post with the output of `print(response.text)` without any modification

Comment: @Corralien: I cannot post the content since it is confidential (internal news), but I've added the whole structure as I get it from response.text and replaced the content

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. How do you get the `response`?

Comment: @Aquen. I suppose the response.text is a json dict?

Comment: @Corralien: Yes

Comment: Did you try `import json; d = json.loads(response.text)`? to convert it to a dict. After that you can decode the value of the key `td_data`.

Comment: That seems to be the reason. At least it is now printing out the content in the cmd correctly. Thank you!